# Given a rational matrix $Q$, can we generate $\langle Q^{i}(v)\mid i\in\mathbb Z,v\in\mathbb Z^{2}\rangle$ using only non-negative powers of a matrix?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory

I have copied this question from [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4765627/976076), thank you to those who helped me to improve the question. (apology if you have seen this question already)

Let $Q $ be a matrix in  $ \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q}) $.   Consider the group $ \langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in 
\mathbb Z^{2}  \rangle$ under vector addition. I would like to know if this group can be generated using only the non-negative power of a matrix, i.e.

**Question**: does there exists a matrix $P \in \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$  , such that

$$  \langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in \mathbb  Z^{2}  \rangle = \langle P^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb N, v \in \mathbb  Z^{2}  \rangle . 
$$

I can show that such $P$ exists when there exists $n \in \mathbb  Z$, such that $Q^n$ has the following form

- Integer matrix (We can take $Q$ to be $P^{-1}$);
- upper triangular matrix (hence diagonal matrix).

However, for a general matrix $Q$, it is quite difficult to compute  $\langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in \mathbb  Z^{2}  \rangle$ by hand. Another difficulty is that we can't put a rational matrix in echelon form.

I feel the Cayley-Hamilton theorem might be useful, because it tells us that, for $i\in \mathbb N$, $Q^{i}$ can be written as linear combinations of $Q$ and $I$ with rational coefficients, similarly, $Q^{-i}$ can be written as linear combinations of $Q^{-1}$ and $I$ with rational coefficients. It is not obvious if this would help because of the fact that the coefficient might be non-integer.

Any ideas/references would be really appreciated. Thank you!

(This was an idea I had to find [prime index subgroup of $\langle Q^{i}(\mathbb Z^{2}) \mid i \in \mathbb Z \rangle$ that is invariant under $Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759462/976076))

P.S: Eventually, I would like to check if the statements hold for matrices in $ \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{Q}) $, so a counterexample in **any** dimension would help.

Comment: I can show that $\langle Q^i(\mathbb{Z}^2) \, \vert i \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle = \langle P^i(\mathbb{Z}^2) \, \vert i \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$ holds for some $P \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ if any of the following conditions is satisfied: (1) $Q$ is conjugate to a triangular matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, (2) $\text{tr}(Q) \in \mathbb{Z}$ (3) $\text{tr}(Q) / \det(Q) \in \mathbb{Z}$, (4) $\det(Q) = 1$. Sadly, I have no counter-example to offer.

Comment: That's okay, thank you for your time!

Comment: There is a sub-problem that you could settle first, if it's not already the case: characterise the quadratic irrational numbers $q$ for which we can find a quadratic number $p = p(q)$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[p]$. (This is, in some natural sense, stronger than your condition and it holds under any of the conditions labelled from (2) to (4); see the above list).

Comment: @LucGuyot Would it be okay for you to put your comment as an answer for now? (I might need some time to think about the subproblem, as Number theory is not my strong suit)

Comment: I will, for sure, but I doubt that I'll be on time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a **long comment** posted as an answer on OP's request.
The first three claims below are known to the OP.  They serve as an introduction to our Claims 4 and 5.

Our claims describe a wider set of matrices in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ with the desired property but do **not** offer any counter-example.

We have outlined **two sub-problems**, namely Problems 1 and 2 below, which may appeal to MO users with a keen interest in **number theory**.

For $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, we set $$G(Q)  := \langle Q^i(\mathbb{Z}^2) \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle \subset \mathbb{Q}^2,$$
$$G_{\ge 0}(Q)  := \langle Q^i(\mathbb{Z}^2) \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \rangle \subseteq G(Q).$$

We say that $Q$ enjoys *Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$* if $G(Q) = G_{\ge 0}(P)$ for some $P \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

**Remark 1**. Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and $A \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Then the following are equivalent:

- $Q$ has Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$.
- $AQA^{-1}$ has Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$.

> **Claim 1.**
> Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. If $Q$ has a rational eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $2$, then $Q$ satisfies Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$.

Let $r \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$. We define the integer $\pi(r)$ as the product of the primes $p$ such that the $p$-valuation $\nu_p(r)$ of $r$ is not zero.
It is readily checked that
$$\mathbb{Z}[r, r^{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\pi(r)}].$$

**Example.**
As $\nu_2(\frac{2}{3}) = - \nu_3(\frac{2}{3}) = 1$, we have $\pi(\frac{2}{3}) = 6$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{2}] = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}]$.

We denote by $(e_1, e_2)$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

> *Proof of Claim 1*. Let $u = (u_1, u_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ be an eigenvector of $Q$ such that $\gcd(u_1, u_2) = 1$.
> Thanks to Remark 1, we can replace $u$ by $e_1$ without loss of generality. Hence we can assume that $Q$ is of the form
> $\begin{pmatrix}
> a & \frac{p}{q} \\
> 0 & a
> \end{pmatrix}$
> with $a \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ such that $\gcd(p, q) = 1$. Let $i \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$. It readily follows from the identities $$Q^i = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a^i & \frac{pia^{i - 1}}{q} \\
> 0 & a^i
> \end{pmatrix},
> Q^{-i} =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a^{-i} & -\frac{pia^{- i - 1}}{q} \\
> 0 & a^{-i}
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$ that $G(Q) = \frac{1}{q} \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\pi(a)}] \times \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\pi(a)}] = G_{\ge 0}(P)$ for
> $P = \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{1}{\pi(a)} & \frac{1}{q} \\
> 0 & \frac{1}{\pi(a)}  
> \end{pmatrix}$.

Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we define the ring $$\mathbb{Z}_{(n)} : = \{ \frac{p}{q} \, \vert \, p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\},\, \gcd(q, n) = 1 \}.$$

It is well-known and easy to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]$ ($n \neq 0$) and $\mathbb{Z}_{(n)}$ is are Euclidean domains.

Given $n, d \in \mathbb{Z}$, we denote by $[n]_d$ the congruence class of $n$ modulo $d$, that is, $[n]_d = n + d\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Z}/d \mathbb{Z}$.
We shall omit the subscript $d$ and simply write $[n]$ when there is no risk of ambiguity.

> **Claim 2.**
> Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. If $Q$ has two distinct rational eigenvalues, then $Q$ satisfies Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$.

> *Proof*. Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ be the eigenvalues of $Q$. Thanks to Remark 1, we can assume without loss of generality that $Q(e_1) = a e_1$.
> Let $e = (m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ be an eigenvector of $Q$ associated to $b$ such that $m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ and $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. Then we have $e_2 = \frac{1}{n} e - \frac{m}{n}e_1$ so that
> $$(1) \quad G(Q) = \langle a^i e_1, \frac{b^i}{n} e - \frac{ma^i}{n}e_1 \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle.$$ Therefore we have
> $\Gamma \subseteq G(Q) \subseteq \frac{1}{n} \Gamma$ with
> $\Gamma := \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\pi(a)}]e_1 \oplus  \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\pi(b)}]e$.
> Let $d_a(n) = \Pi_{\nu_p(a) = 0} p^{\nu_p(n)}$ and define $d_b(n)$ similarly.
> It is easy to check that $\Gamma /n\Gamma \simeq \mathbb{Z}/d_a(n)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/d_b(n)\mathbb{Z}$.
> Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ be such that $[\alpha] \in \mathbb{Z}/d_a(n)\mathbb{Z}$ is the image of $a$ by the natural map
> $\mathbb{Z}_{(d_a(n))} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{(d_a(n))} / d_a(n) \mathbb{Z}_{(d_a(n))} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/d_a(n) \mathbb{Z}$.
> Define $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ in a similar way.
> It follows from $(1)$ that $G(Q)/\Gamma \simeq nG(Q)/n\Gamma$ identifies with the subgroup
> $\langle (-m [\alpha]^i, [\beta]^i) \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}/d_a(n)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/d_b(n)\mathbb{Z}$.
> Write $a = \frac{k}{l}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}, l \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ and $\gcd(k, l) = 1$
> and let $\omega(l)$ be the order of $[l]$ in the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/d_a(n)\mathbb{Z}$.
> Let $x = k l^{\omega(l) - 1}$, set $\rho(a) = x^{\omega(x) - 1}$ and define $\rho(b)$ similarly.
> Consider now the matrix $P \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ defined by $P(e_1) = \frac{1}{\rho(a)}e_1$ and $P(e) = \frac{1}{\rho(b)}e$.
> Then we have $\Gamma \subseteq G_{\ge 0}(P) \subseteq \frac{1}{n} \Gamma$ and the quotient $G_{\ge 0}(P)/\Gamma$  identifies with the subgroup
> $\langle (-m [\alpha^i], [\beta^i]) \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}/d_a(n)\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/d_b(n)\mathbb{Z}$.
> Consequently, the equality $G_{\ge 0}(P) = G(Q)$ holds true if and only if $G_{\ge 0}(P)/H = G(Q)/H$ where $H = \Gamma + \mathbb{Z}e_2$. Let $d = \gcd(d_a(n), d_b(n))$.
> Then the previous condition can be rephrased as follows: the equality $G_{\ge 0}(P) = G(Q)$ holds true if and only if
> $C_{\ge 0} := \langle [\alpha^i - \beta^i] \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \rangle$
> and $C := \langle [\alpha]^i - [\beta]^i  \, \vert \, i \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle$ define the same subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$.
> Since $[\alpha]^{-i} - [\beta]^{-i} = -[\alpha \beta]^{-i} [\alpha^i - \beta^i]$ holds in $\mathbb{Z}/d \mathbb{Z}$ for every $i \ge 0$, we infer that $C_{\ge 0} = C$,
> which completes the proof.

> **Corollary 1**. Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. If $Q$ is the conjugate in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ of a triangular matrix, then $Q$ satisfies Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$.

> *Proof*. Apply Claims 1 and 2.

> **Claim 3**. Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. If $Q$ is the $n$-th root of a matrix with integer coefficients for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$, then $Q$ has Property $(\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0})$.

> *Proof*. It follows from the hypothesis that $G(Q) = \langle Q^i(\mathbb{Z}^2) \, \vert \, i \le n \rangle$. As $Q^{-n}(G(Q)) = G(Q)$, we infer that $G(Q) = \langle Q^i(\mathbb{Z}^2) \, \vert \, i \le 0 \rangle = G_{\ge 0}(Q^{-1})$.

**Definition.** We say that $Q$ satisfies *Property $\mathcal{P}_1$* is there is $P \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $$\mathbb{Z}[Q, Q^{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[P].$$

**Remark 2.** Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Then $G(P)$ is naturally a $\mathbb{Z}[Q, Q^{-1}]$-module with generating set $\{e_1, e_2\}$. Hence Property $\mathcal{P}_1$ implies Property $\mathcal{P}_{\ge 0}$.

> **Claim 4**. Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and assume that at least one of the following holds:
>
> - $(i)$ $\det(Q) = \pm 1$,
> - $(ii)$ $\text{tr}(Q) \in \mathbb{Z}$,
> - $(iii)$ $\text{tr}(Q) / \det(Q) \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Then $Q$ satisfies Property $\mathcal{P}_1$.

We denote by $I$ the identity matrix of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

> *Proof*. By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, we have: $Q^2 - \text{tr}(Q) Q + \det(Q)I = 0$, which is equivalent to
> $Q^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(Q)}(\text{tr}(Q)I - Q)$.
> If $\det(Q) \in \{-1,1\}$, then $Q^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[Q]$ so that $\mathbb{Z}[Q, Q^{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[Q]$.
> If $\text{tr}(Q) / \det(Q) \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\det(Q)}Q]$.
> As $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\det(Q)}Q] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[Q, Q^{-1}]$, we deduce that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\det(Q)}Q] = \mathbb{Z}[Q, Q^{-1}]$.
> To check the remaining condition, it suffices to swap the rôles of $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$ in the previous argument.

**Remark 3**. Let $Q \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and let $q \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ denote an eigenvalue of $Q$. If the characteristic polynomial of $Q$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., $Q$ has no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{Q}$, then the map $Q \mapsto q$ induces a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[Q, Q^{-1}] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}]$.

**Problem 1**. Characterise the [irrational quadratic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational_number) $q$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}]  = \mathbb{Z}[p]$ for some quadratic number $p = p(q)$.

The following claim is an incremental progress towards a solution of Problem 1.

> **Claim 5**. Let $q$ be an [irrational quadratic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational_number) and write $q = \frac{\eta}{\delta}$ where $\eta$
> is an [irrational quadratic integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer) and $\delta \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. Then the following hold.
>
> - The inclusion $\mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\delta \eta}]$ holds true if and only if $\frac{\text{tr}(\eta)}{\delta} = \frac{\text{tr}(q)}{\det(q)}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\delta \eta}]$.
> - The inclusion $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\delta \eta}] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}]$ holds true if and only if $\frac{1}{\delta}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}]$.

For $x \in \mathbb{Q}[q]$, we denote by $\overline{x}$ the *conjugate* of $x$, that is, the image of $x$ by the $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[q]$ with order $2$.

> *Proof of Claim 5.* Clearly, $q^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{\delta \eta}]$.
> To prove the first statement, we observe that $\frac{1}{\delta \eta} = \frac{\overline{\eta}}{\delta \overline{\eta}\eta} = \frac{\text{tr}(\eta) - \eta}{\delta \det(\eta)}$.
> For the second statement, we observe that $\frac{1}{\delta \eta} = \frac{q^{-1}}{\delta^2}$.

**Problem 2**. Let $q$ be an [irrational quadratic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational_number). Compute $\mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}]  \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

**Remark 4**. Write $\det(q) = \frac{d_1}{d_2}$ and $\text{tr}(q) = \frac{t_1}{t_2}$ with $d_i, t_i \in \mathbb{Z}, \gcd(d_1, d_2) = \gcd(t_1, t_2) = 1$. Set $\delta = d_2 t_2$. Then $\eta$ is an algebraic integer and it is easy to verify that $\mathbb{Z}[\det(q)t_2, d_2 \text{tr}(q)] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}] \cap \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}] \subseteq D[\eta] = D + D\eta$ where $D := \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{d_1 \delta}]$, so that $\mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq D$.

We claim (to be confirmed with a proof) that $N \cdot D \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[q, q^{-1}]$ for some integer $N > 0$.

We can make use of Claim 5 to derive Claim 4. Indeed, keeping the notation of Remark 4, it is immediate to check that $\eta = d_2 t_2 q$ is an algebraic integer, $\text{tr}(\eta) = d_2 t_1$ and $\det(\eta) = d_1 d_2 t_2^2$.

Comment: +1. Can you recall the definition of a quadratic number?

Comment: Maybe to solve Problem 1 it can be helpful given a quadratic number $p$ to look for all units $q$ in $\mathbb Z[p]$ such that $p\in\mathbb Z[q,q^{-1}]$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for your kind interest and comments. I have added a few wiki links.

Comment: Thank for the links. So let $p$ be an irrational quadratic number. I expect units in $\mathbb Z[p]$ can be described as follows. There are integer numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a\ne 0$, the greatest common divisor of $a$, $b$, and $c$ equals $1$ and 
$ap^2+bp+c=0$. Suppose that we have polynomials $r(x),s(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $r(p)s(p)=1$. Then $p$ is a root of the polynomial $r(x)s(x)-1$, so I expect that $ax^2+bx+c$ divides $r(x)s(x)-1$. So we have to look for such triples of polynomials $r(x)$, $s(x)$, and $ax^2+bx+c$ from $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: Similarly we can look for rationals in $\mathbb Z[q,q^{-1}]$. Namely, let  $a$, $b$, and $c$ be integer numbers such that $a\ne 0$, the greatest common divisor of $a$, $b$, and $c$ equals $1$, and $aq^2+bq+c=0$. Then I expect that for any $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, $\frac mn\in\mathbb Z[q,q^{-1}]$ iff there exist a polynomial $r(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ and a nonnegative integer $k$ such that $ax^2+bx+c$ divides $nr(x)-mx^k$.

Comment: Concerning the previous comment. If $a=1$ then we can reduce $r(x)$ and $s(x)$ to polynomials of degree $1$. Let $r(x)=r_1x+r_0$ and $s(x)=s_1x+s_0$. Then $x^2+bx+c$ divides $$(r_1x+r_0)(s_1x+s_0)-1=r_1s_1x^2+(r_1s_0+s_1r_0)x+r_0s_0-1.$$ It follows $r_1s_0+s_1r_0=r_1s_1b$ and $r_0s_0-1=r_1s_1c$. The latter equality implies that $r_0$ is coprime with $r_1$. Then the former equality implies $r_1|s_1$. Similarly we can show that $s_1|r_1$. So $r_1=\pm s_1$.